# How to make annotationProcessor transitive from custom lib

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, lib, transitive-dependency

I'm using my own lib, which configuring core dependencies and other stuff for micro-service product (some kind of custom starter).

To make dependencies transitive (auto-import in inherited projects) i'm using gradle api(dependency) in lib like

```
api(libs.bundles.util) //dependency alias from version-catalog
```

Is there any way to make scope annotationProcessor() transitive like api() for using it similar? The solution i want should looks like this, or describe why i can't do it.

```
apiAnnotationProcessor(libs.mapstruct.processor) //interesting in transitive mapstruct and lombok processors
```